# Dash sign in file .bib is double when compile it to pdf file

Tags: bibtex, xetex

Why bibtext file:

```
...
pages = "419-444",
...
```

generates

```
419--444
```

for me in pdf?

Comment: It shouldn't. So give a MWE that produces the effect. BTW it should be `pages = "419--444"` in bibtex file since it is a page range.

Comment: @HarishKumar - Most bibtex bibliography styles automatically convert a single dash in the `pages` field to `--`. It is then the job of LaTeX (or XeLaTeX) to typeset `--` as an en-dash.

Comment: @Mico Really? It is new to me. :)

Comment: We need to know which document class and which bibliography style you use. By the way, did you enable TeX-style ligatures (such as `--` being typeset as an en-dash)? You can do this either with an option to `\setmainfont` or via `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}` after loading `fontspec` but *before* loading any fonts.

Comment: All, now my problem has solved by using - (non-ascii dash) instead of - (ascii minus sign).

Comment: @Mico Imho Ligatures=TeX is the default now for the text fonts. terces907: Are you sure your system is up-to-date?

Comment: BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2014/MacPorts 2014_4); 
kpathsea version 6.2.0; 
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014/MacPorts 2014_4); 
kpathsea version 6.2.0

Comment: @terces907 - Which version of `fontspec` do you use?